# Java - How to write iterator that iterates through values of a HashSet within a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, set

I've been given a problem where I have to write an iterator for an AbstractMap where the values are represented in a HashSet. This is the class that I am working with:

`public class SetMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, HashSet<V>> implements Iterable<V>`

The instructions I have been given are as follows:

"Implement the iterator such that only values V are traversed. Values are traversed first in descending order of the size of HashSet objects associated with keys, and then in the iterator order for the HashSet."

I am basically unsure of how to approach writing my custom `hasNext()` and `Next()`, considering I am only supposed to traverse the HashSet within the Map.

I am new to Java, so traversing multidimensional maps, especially with sets as some of values, is very confusing to me.

An example of what my main function could do-

```
SetMap<String, Integer> map = new SetMap<>();

map.addValue("B", 4);
map.addValue("A", 0);
map.addValue("A", 1);
map.addValue("B", 3);
map.addValue("A", 2);
    for (Integer value : map) {

        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

-is to produce something like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Any assistance, or relevant resources, would be much appreciated.

Comment: The requirement "Values are traversed first in descending order of the size of HashSet objects associated with keys" means that you first (when iterator is requested) have to retrieve all values of the map and put them in an array, then sorting these `HashSet` items by size. Then you basically iterate over this array and nested for each array item over the `HashSet`  elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use HashSet's `get(String s)`

```
SetMap<String, Integer> map = new SetMap<>();

map.addValue("B", 4);
map.addValue("A", 0);
map.addValue("A", 1);
map.addValue("B", 3);
map.addValue("A", 2);
for (String s : map) {

    System.out.println(map.get(value));
}
```

}